# TextBox.ScrollToEnd doesn't work when the TextBox is in a non-active tab

Tags: wpf, textbox, scroll

Our application starts several background processes and put their output into TextBoxes - each in a separate TabItem in a TabControl. I want the TextBoxes to automatically scroll to show the last output line, so in the data handling function that adds the output/error line to the text box, I also call TextBox.ScrollToEnd():

```
void OnServerProcessOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                TextBox tb = getServerProcessOutputTextBox(sender);
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
                    tb.ScrollToEnd();
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

This works great for the TextBox in the active tab, but when I switch to another tab, I see that it wasn't scrolled down to the end.

Is this a known problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Here is an answer for how to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055720/scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-single-line-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the CaretIndex:

```
   if (tb != null) 
   { 
       tb.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine); 
       tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
       tb.ScrollToEnd(); 
   }
```

Comment: This solution wouldn't work for me unless the TextBox had focus: tb.Focus().

Comment: This 10 yr old bug still persists. If you programmatically move the focus away after this, then it will still not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug... you should report it on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/)