# Scrolling to the end of a single line WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

This seems like such a simple thing but I just can't get it to work.

I have a single line text box that has a lot of text.  What I want to happen is that whenever the text box receives focus, it scrolls to the end of the text so that it comes into view and the cursor is at the end ready to accept new text.

In the text box's GotFocus event I call textBox.ScrollToEnd().  It looks like all this does is move the cursor to the end of the text box but not actually bring the end into view.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to do it using these members:

- [`TextBoxBase.ScrollToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx)
- [`TextBox.CaretIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex.aspx)

---

EDIT: not sure why ScrollToEnd isn't working... Anyway, this code works:

```
textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
```

Comment: I tried calling textBox.ScrollToEnd() in GotFocus but it doesn't bring the end of the string into focus.  Setting the CaretIndex just moves the caret position but doesn't bring that position into view.  So if my text box contains more text than can be fit and I want to scroll to the end whenever it gets focus, how would I do that?  All I have in my small sample is a single textBox, Width="80" and in its GotFocus method I tried TextBoxBase.ScrollToEnd, TextBox.CaretIndex, and a combination of the two to scroll to the end of a long string.  If you got it to work, can you post a sample?

Comment: Thanks.  This works better but it acted a little strange depending on where the caret was last when you left the textBox.  It looks like it has something to do with the horizontal offset of the textBox.  I changed the last line to read textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Math.Max(rect.Right, textBox.HorizontalOffset)); and it seems to work fine now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had to make a
    textBox.Focus()
right before to make it work.

Comment: I had to do ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0) first to cause the text to be loaded from data binding

Answer (score 5):

It is true - setting the caret property from code doesn't affect the view; and the caret can go outside the visible part.

```
kb_target_box.Focus(); // just for sure
Rect rect = kb_target_box.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(kb_target_box.CaretIndex);
kb_target_box.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Math.Max((kb_target_box.HorizontalOffset + rect.Left - (kb_target_box.ActualWidth - 40)), 0.0));
```

h-scroll will follow the caret after it comes closer than 40 to the right TextBox border.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
textBox.CaretIndex = txt.Text.Length;  
textBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my textbox was inside a scrollviewer and I had to call ScrollToEnd() for scrollviewer instead textbox.

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer">
        <TextBox TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TextChanged"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

CODE

```
private void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollviewer.ScrollToEnd();
}
```