# How to prevent TextBox to move scrollbar and text when writing text to it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Whenever I write line to TextBox that is wider than width of textbox the scrollbar moves with appended text. The problem is I want to have scrollbar maximally moved to the left (at the beginning of the line). Can be moved at the end of writing or just fixed and then moved manually by scrollbar.
My question can be duplicate, because I don't even know how to name this issue.

Maybe screenshots can easier introduce my problem. On the left there is a position of a text in TextBox automatically moved and on the right side is position of thet text in TextBox manually moved by me with scrollbar.
[image: Example]

Comment: You should change `slider` to `scrollbar`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, renamed it in description, it is a scrollbar. my bad - introducing to windows apps, don't know how to correctly name some things and also i'm not native english speaker.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056132/2029607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [FastColoredTextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting-2) in my project and I just found method `my_text_box.ScrollLeft();` and works fine. Whenever text appends on textbox it moves to the left, no flickering etc.